# Skype - Is there a keyboard shortcut to answer a call?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, skype

Is there a keyboard shortcut for Skype (preferably for OSX) which allows me to answer the call? Or do I have to click the green button on the popup Incoming Call window?

I've tried to make an OSX Hotkey (via System Preferences > Keyboard) - but I dont know what the menu item is called to answer a call.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
I have already looked at these resourced:

- https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12074/what-keyboard-shortcuts-can-i-use-with-skype-for-mac-os-x
- https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12024/what-are-hotkeys-and-how-to-use-them-mac

Answer (score 3):

Simplified, with credit to [Brett Terpstra](http://brettterpstra.com/2010/10/03/answer-skype-with-a-hotkey/):

It looks like the easiest way to accomplish this is to create an AppleScript that sends a command to the Skype API to answer or hang up the call. Here it is, in all its glory:

```
tell application "System Events" to set _proc to name of processes as list

if _proc contains "Skype" then

    tell application "Skype"

        set calls to send command "SEARCH ACTIVECALLS" script name "AnsweringScript"
        set callID to last word of calls
        if callID is not "CALLS" then
            set status to send command "GET CALL " & callID & " STATUS" script name "AnsweringScript"
            if last word of status is "RINGING" then
                send command "ALTER CALL " & callID & " ANSWER" script name "AnsweringScript"
                return
            else
                send command "ALTER CALL " & callID & " HANGUP" script name "AnsweringScript"
            end if
        end if

    end tell

end if
```

To turn that into a keyboard shortcut, save it as an application and then install [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), which is a piece of software that lets you assign keyboard shortcuts to applications.

Comment: Neat. And to Call? Video Call? IM?